# Javascript calculate the average of different strings in div element with only a class without changing html

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a plugin on a site for school. I can only use javascript. I have to make a bergekining with any number like in the example (1 + 68 + 7 + 98 + 12 + 23) / (10 + 100 + 10 + 100 + 20 + 100) * 100.
ibb.co/r56KmQS the result must look like this
thanks for your time

```
//only the beginning    
var i;
    var a;
    var b;
    var p1 = [];
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName('course_eval_cell');
    for (i = 0; i < el[i].length; i++) {
        if (el[i].innerHTML.charAt(i) = "/") {
            for (a = 0; a < i - 1; a++) {
                p1 += el[i].innerHTML.charAt(a);
            }
            alert(p1);
        }
    }
```

```
<div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade" smsctip="true">1/10</div>
<div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade" smsctip="true">68/100</div>
<div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade" smsctip="true">7/10</div>
<div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade" smsctip="true">98/100</div>
<div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade" smsctip="true">12/20</div>
<div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade" smsctip="true">23/100</div>
<div class="course_eval_cell"></div>
<div class="course_eval_cell" id="12"></div>
<script>
 // code here
</script>
```

I expect the output of (1 + 68 + 7 + 98 + 12 + 23) / (10 + 100 + 10 + 100 + 20 + 100) * 100 to be 61.4

Comment: A "bergekining"? Can you explain what that is? You mean  "calculation"? Also, where does the "1 + " come from?

Comment: oops my apologies. yes I meant calculation

Comment: btw, don't you need to add all parts with their denominator?

Comment: here are some hints. 1) Use `.textContent` to get the text from the element. 2) you can use `String.prototype.split()` to parse the string into correct/total# values. 3) you will need to use `parseInt` to do the math.

Comment: The right way to add fractions is to first transform each fraction to have the *same* denominator. Your formula is wrong.

Comment: The calculation is correct normally

Comment: @trincot - this is an average calculation - total number of questions divided by total opportunity.

Comment: Oh right, not an addition of fractions. I see. Would be interesting to have this information in the question though.

Comment: Thank you @RandyCasburn for your hint

Comment: What are the two empty `div` elements for?

Comment: @trincot my apologies

Comment: @trincot the last one is for innerHTML the result

Comment: And the other one?

Comment: https://ibb.co/r56KmQS the result must look like this

Comment: I don't see how that image corresponds to your question. Where is the result?

Comment: @trincot this was before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If I understand your question** then How about this way?

```js
//only the beginning    
var i, a, b;
var p1 = 0;
var p2 = 0;
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('hasGrade');
for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  [a, b] = el[i].innerHTML.split('/');
  p1 += parseInt(a);
  p2 += parseInt(b);
}
result = ((p1 / p2) * 100).toFixed(2);
console.log(result);
document.getElementById("12").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade" smsctip="true">1/10</div>
<div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade" smsctip="true">68/100</div>
<div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade" smsctip="true">7/10</div>
<div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade" smsctip="true">98/100</div>
<div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade" smsctip="true">12/20</div>
<div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade" smsctip="true">23/100</div>
<div class="course_eval_cell"></div>
<div class="course_eval_cell" id="12"></div>
```

Comment: Thank You very much, you help me a lot. But I still have a problem with getting this for more lines "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56307994/total-number-of-questions-divided-by-total-opportunity-only-use-javascript-div". Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it. The idea is to:

- Iterate the elements, for instance with `reduce` (see further down why this is a good candidate)
- Split their text content into two parts using `split`
- Convert those parts from string to number using the unary `+` operator
- Sum the first parts and sum the second parts using `reduce`, which gives two results (as an array of two numbers)
- Perform the division. Again you can use `reduce` for this (it makes it *functional programming* style)
- Format the result with two decimals using `toFixed`

```js
document.getElementById("12").textContent = [...document.querySelectorAll(".hasGrade")]
    .reduce((acc, elem) => {
        const parts = elem.textContent.split("/");
        return acc.map((sum, i) => sum += +parts[i]);
    }, [0, 0])
    .reduce((a, b) => a/b*100)
    .toFixed(2);
```

```html
<div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade" smsctip="true">1/10</div>
<div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade" smsctip="true">68/100</div>
<div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade" smsctip="true">7/10</div>
<div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade" smsctip="true">98/100</div>
<div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade" smsctip="true">12/20</div>
<div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade" smsctip="true">23/100</div>
<div class="course_eval_cell"></div>
<div class="course_eval_cell" id="12"></div>
```