# total number of questions divided by total opportunity. Only use JavaScript. div elements

Tags: javascript

I have already asked this for 1 list but I can't get it to work for 2 or more lists, the result always shows NaN. I have to calculate the average per list separately. the formula for the example is "(10 + 61) / (10 + 100) * 100". Here is a link how it looks in total "https://ibb.co/6g2bCYJ"
Thank you for your time

```
<div class="grid_course_evals" style="width: 1061px;">

                <div class="course_eval_row cf" style="width:770px;">
                    <div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade" smsctip="true">10/10</div>
                    <div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade">61/100</div>
                    <div class="course_eval_cell"></div>
                    <div class="course_eval_cell"></div>
                    <div class="course_eval_cell"></div>
                    <div class="course_eval_cell"></div>
                    <div class="course_eval_cell"></div>
                    <div class="course_eval_cell"></div>
                    <div class="course_eval_cell"></div>
                    <div class="course_eval_cell"></div>
                    <div class="course_eval_cell"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="course_eval_row cf" style="width:770px;">
                    <div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade isLow" smsctip="true">5/12</div>
                    <div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade  ">16/24</div>
                    <div class="course_eval_cell"></div>
                    <div class="course_eval_cell"></div>
                    <div class="course_eval_cell"></div>
                    <div class="course_eval_cell"></div>
                    <div class="course_eval_cell"></div>
                    <div class="course_eval_cell"></div>
                    <div class="course_eval_cell"></div>
                    <div class="course_eval_cell"></div>
                    <div class="course_eval_cell"></div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

```
 function start() {
    var xclass = document.getElementsByClassName("course_eval_row");

    var i, a, b, k;
    var p1 = 0;
    var p2 = 0;
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName('course_eval_cell');
    var result;
for (i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
   result = "result";
   xclass = document.getElementsByClassName("course_eval_row")[i];
   xclass.style.width = xclass.clientWidth + 70 + "px";
   a = 0;
   b = 0;
   p1 = 0;
   p2 = 0;
for (k = 0; k < document.getElementsByClassName('course_eval_row')[i].length; k++) {
  [a, b] = document.getElementsByClassName('course_eval_cell')[k].innerHTML.split('/');
  p1 += parseInt(a);
  p2 += parseInt(b);
}
result = ((p1 / p2) * 100).toFixed(2);
  xclass.innerHTML += "<div id='extra_Gem' class='course_eval_cell'><strong>" + result + " %</strong></div>";
}
 }
```

I expect the output of example 1 of the first div group to be 64.55, but the actual output is NaN

Comment: `parseInt` on an empty string returns `NaN`. You need to handle what should happen when you get an element with no content inside (or no numeric value on each side of the `/` in your content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example HTML, some of the `course_eval_cell` divs are empty.  These will be empty strings when you fetch their `innerHTML`.

When you call `split` on those empty string, the result is just another empty string.

You attempt to assign the second character in that empty string to `b` but it will be `undefined` because the empty string has length 0.

You call `parseInt` on this value of `undefined`, which always results in `NaN`. Adding `NaN` to another number also results in `NaN`.  In fact any other arithmetic operation involving `NaN` will result in `NaN`.

When you call `toFixed(2)` on `NaN`, it results in the string `"NaN"`.

A possible fix for you might be to filter out empty strings so those values are not included in your calculation.  You could try something like:

```
var cellValue = document.getElementsByClassName('course_eval_cell')[k];
if (cellValue) {
  [a, b] = cellValue.split('/');
  p1 += parseInt(a);
  p2 += parseInt(b);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm still trying but this helpt me a lot!!